# The meaning of "just" here

Tags: phrases

8:00 pm : I started to drink.

9:00 pm : I finished drinking.

9:02 pm : I was heading out the door.

9:03 pm : I met old friend Suzi and we decided to drink more just two of us.

9:30 pm (now): We drink.

In this situation, I said like

> A. I ***had just finished*** drinking and just as I was about to leave, I happened to meet old friend from college at the bar, Suzi. So, we decided to drink more and we're here at another bar drinking.

Here, A means B or C ?

> B. ***Only a short while ago from now,*** I finished drinking and just as I was about to leave, I happened to meet old friend from college at the bar, Suzi. So, we decided to drink more and we're here at another bar drinking.
>
> C. I finished drinking and was about to leave, ***and only a short while after I finished drinking and was about to leave,*** I happened to meet old friend from college at the bar, Suzi. So, we decided to drink more and we're here at another bar drinking.

I want to know the meaning of "just" here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

C

The tense used is the past perfect "I had finished", this tense implies a time before another event. The other event is "meeting Suzi", and the adverb "just" indicates that the event "I had finished" occurred immediately before "meeting Suzi"

To suggest the meaning B you could try

> I just met an old friend! I'd been drinking and when I was about to leave I bumped into Suzi. So we decided to ....